# Understanding how this javascript slideshow works with key value pairs

Tags: javascript

This may seem like a bit of a newbie question, but I’ve just started a new job and am trying to understand more about and roughly how the following javascript code works:

```
app.placementOptions["cycleslideshow"] = {
    ".cycle-slideshow" : {
            speed: 500
          , timeout: 8000
          , fx: "fade"
          , pager: ".decoration-right"
    },
    ".regen-slideshow .cycle-slideshow" : {
            speed: 800
          , timeout: 12000
          , fx: "scrollHorz"
          , pager: ".decoration-right"
    }
  };
```

Note that this above code apparently styles the slideshow buttons to be the small circles at the bottom right of the area above the fold on this site: https://www.ccht.org.uk

And the full JS for that is here: https://www.ccht.org.uk/js/plugins.js

Can someone explain what the snippet code roughly does? What is it? Is it JavaScript OOP with key value pairs? Can someone link to an article to help me read up about it? My employer may use BX Slider: https://bxslider.com

I was told that this part of the code is key: `pager: ".decoration-right"` - the company uses the LESS CSS preprocessor if that makes a difference.

And is Stack Overflow the right place to put this kind of question that has no actual solution (not that I won't accept any answer)? Hopefully it won't get closed as being broad. Thanks for any advice here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't looked at your full code yet, but this code is essentially just setting the `cycleslideshow` property of the `placementOptions` object (which is itself a property of the `app` object) to be equal to everything to the right of the `=` sign.

So basically, you have an object app which could be intialized like this:

```
const app = {
    placementOptions: {}
}
```

Then with the snippet above, you're creating a new key on the `placementOptions` object, which could have also just been written as `app.placementOptions.cycleslideshow` in this case (in other words, the bracket notation wasn't needed).

The cycle slideshow object has two keys, which are both JavaScript objects representing collections of CSS rules, so this object is likely referenced when styling some DOM element, as you said, and can easily be accessed by the class names. In this case, wrapping the property names in quotes is required, because valid property names can't begin with `.` or have spaces in them unless they're wrapped as strings like this.

The `pager` line may have particular significance to the CSS, but has no particular JavaScript significance. Each of these CSS properties are just keys on their respective objects.

The following code is equivalent to your original snippet (not taking into account any additional keys/values that `app` or `placementOptions` may have:

```
const app = {
    placementOptions: {
        cylceslideshow: {}
    }
}

app.placementOptions.cycleslideshow['.cycle-slideshow'] = {
      speed: 500
    , timeout: 8000
    , fx: "fade"
    , pager: ".decoration-right"
};

app.placementOptions.cycleslideshow['.regen-slideshow .cycle-slideshow'] = {
      speed: 800
    , timeout: 12000
    , fx: "scrollHorz"
    , pager: ".decoration-right"
};
```

Note that in this case, where bracket notation is used, it is required, for the same reason I mentioned above. You wouldn't neccessarily write the code this way, the way it is written is already fine, but this is just breaking it down into smaller parts for you and showing you they're the same.

In either case, you could access the object like this:

```
console.log(app.placementOptions.cycleslideshow['.cycle-slideshow']);
// logs:
/*
{
    speed: 500,
    timeout: 8000,
    fx: "fade",
    pager: ".decoration-right"
}
*/
```

Or access part of the object:

```
console.log(app.placementOptions.cycleslideshow['.cycle-slideshow'].speed);
// logs: 500
```

Overall the question is a bit broad, but hopefully this helps.

---

**EDIT:** not sure how beginner or basic you're looking for, but here's an article that goes over some of the basics about working with JS Objects: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/lets-explore-objects-in-javascript-4a4ad76af798.

freeCodeCamp itself has plenty of beginner resources (articles, challenges, videos, etc.) for learning JS.

Comment: Wow. What a great answer this is. THANK YOU!

Comment: Glad it helped :-)

Answer (score 1):

The snippet you have provided seems to be simply specifying the configurations for the classes in the HTML, such as `".cycle-slideshow"` and `".regen-slideshow .cycle-slideshow"`.

I'm not sure what the plugin code is doing exactly behind the scenes, but those configuration values specified in the snippet will be read by the plugin by the key "cycleslideshow". The value is the collection of settings specified. This is using the JavaScript object format, similar to JSON.

To find out exactly what each entry from the configuration mean and what the expected values are, you can search their github page since it seems to be open source.